# objective c - hide a custom annotation view

Tags: objective-c

I want to have a custom Annotation view that behaves exactly as the standard one, but mine needs to have an image inside and several texts, that's why I've implemented the tutorial on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html

But my problem is that I want the annotation view to hide and just show a pin, same thing as the default annotation view behaves but all annotations are showing and I cant figure out a way to hide them.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
My current implementation of viewForAnnotation is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
NSLog(@"Item añadido");

static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";



CustomMKAnnotationView *annotationView =

(CustomMKAnnotationView *)[mapa dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

if (annotationView == nil)

{

    annotationView = [[[CustomMKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];

}



annotationView.annotation = annotation;



return annotationView;


}
```

Becuase I need the standard bubble but with an image and a couple of UILabels. But I would like to keep the standard behaviour, that is, there's a pin when the bubble is not showing, and when you tap it shows the bubble. The content of my custom bubble is implemented in "CustomMKAnnotationView".
Which is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (self != nil)

{

    CGRect frame = self.frame;

    frame.size = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);

    self.frame = frame;

    // self. = [super pincolor];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0);

}

return self;

}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

CustomMKAnnotation *custom = (CustomMKAnnotation *)self.annotation;

if (custom != nil)

{   
    NSLog(@"El nombre es: %@", [custom nombre]);

    UILabel *nombre = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UILabel *media = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    PDColoredProgressView *barrita = [[PDColoredProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    [barrita setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.83 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0f]];


    nombre.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    media.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nombre.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Bold" size:14];
    media.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Medium" size:12];
    CGSize size = [[custom nombre] sizeWithFont:nombre.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 20)                                                                             lineBreakMode:nombre.lineBreakMode];

    NSLog(@"el ancho es: %f y alto %f", size.width, size.height);

    nombre.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    media.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    nombre.text = [custom nombre];
    barrita.progress = [custom gente];

    media.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Media %@ años", [custom media]];

    UIImageView *fondo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble_map.png"]];


    nombre.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, size.width, size.height);
    media.frame = CGRectMake(10, size.height + 10, size.width, size.height);
    barrita.frame = CGRectMake(10, media.frame.origin.y + 20, size.width, 10); 
    fondo.frame =  CGRectMake(-((size.width+ 20.0f)/2), -((size.height +10)*2 + 20)-10, size.width+ 20.0f, (size.height +10)*2 + 20);

    fondo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    nombre.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;


    [fondo addSubview:nombre];
    [fondo addSubview:media];
    [fondo addSubview:barrita];
    [self addSubview:fondo];

    [fondo release];
    [nombre release];
    [media release];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean hiding the details of pin, have you tried creating a custom `MKPinAnnotationView` and set its property of `canShowCallout=NO;` ?

In your mapview delegate method :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id    <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

 MKPinAnnotationView*pinView;

if([annotation isKindOfClass:[<yourannotationclass> class]])
{

    static NSString*annoIdentifier=@"AnnotationIdentifier";

    pinView=(MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annoIdentifier];

    if(pinView==nil)
    {
        pinView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annoIdentifier]autorelease ];
    }

    pinView.animatesDrop=NO;
    pinView.canShowCallout=NO;
    pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;


}

   return pinView;
}
```

Comment: I added some code to make it clearer what Im trying, which is basicly imitate the standard behaviour of the annotationview but with my custom annotation view, I need pins, and also those pins to show a bubble when tapped.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm still not clear on your problem, you have a pin when you click on it you get  bubble with images and details ? So what exactly do you need ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be clearer now.The code I've pasted, "draws" in the map bubbles, without a pin. The bubbles are expanded, so if I have 5 locations the map appears full of bubbles. 
I need a behaviour similar to the standard. That is, it first "draws" pins, and when you tap on any of the pins, the Custom Annotation, that I've already implemented that contains several uilabels and an image, shows. The current implementation doesnt show pins and the bubbles are already expanded.

Comment: Ok i understood, but i get the pins using custom `MKPinAnnotationView`  in `viewForAnnotation` like in the code i've pasted. Can you just give that piece of code a try and let me know if you get the pins.

Comment: I tried your code, and it throws an error.
When it's going to add the first annotation. The first "if" for kindOfClass, it's false and it returns "pinView" 
The error is "[MapViewController setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x19a570"

Comment: in place of <yourannotationclass> you should give the class name of annotation class that you are using for the pins. You should be using an annotaion class for title,subtitle etc. ?

Comment: i'm sorry i've a feeling i won't be of much use.

Comment: pinView.canShowCallout=NO; works for me, it prevent to show the MKAnnotationView (ie: the bubble)